# Update React state from outside render when using HOC?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a React widget and using the react-jss HOC for styling. The widget is just a small part of a larger page, and I want to be able to signal it to open or close with a button on another part of the page outside of the React render. Originally I was doing it like this:

```
var modal = ReactDOM.render(<Modal />, document.getElementById('widget'))

// Inside an onClick function
modal.toggleModal()
```

That was before JSS, but now `widget` doesn't return the component, it returns the JSS HOC. I've tried passing `<Widget />` a prop and updating that and then using `widget.forceUpdate()` but that did nothing. Not really sure what else to try at this point. I'm currently just toggling everything outside of React, but I want the component to be able to close itself as well.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'

const styles = {
  show: {
    display: 'block',
  },
  modal: {
    display: 'none',
    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  form: {
    maxWidth: '440px',
    margin: '15px',
    padding: '30px',
    background: '#fff',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: '15px'
  },
  button: {
    width: '100%'
  }
}

class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        show: false
    }

    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this)
  }

  toggleModal() {
      this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
  }  

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props

    return (
      <div className={`${classes.modal} ${this.state.show ? classes.show : ''}`}>
        <form className={classes.form}>
          <label htmlFor="aatitle-field">Title</label>
          <input className={classes.input} type="text" id="aatitle-field" name="title" value="" />
          <button className={`btn ${classes.button}`}>Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default injectSheet(styles)(Modal)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your components code?

Comment: ok, component has been added

Answer (score -2):

First of all, please use the `classnames` library to generate classNames, it's so more elegant.

Secondly, classes are applied in order they are parsed by the brower. So what you're doing is tricky. How can we know if the `modal` class is parsed before `show`? (This is a requirement in your current code). You can simply move the modal declaration before the show declaration in `styles` and surely this will work, but this is a fragile solution. Better is to use a `show` and `hide` class and apply them according the state. This removes the dependency of which style class is loaded first. So remove `display:none` from `modal` and introduce hide:

Something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'

const styles = {
  show: {
    display: 'block',
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  modal: {
    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  form: {
    maxWidth: '440px',
    margin: '15px',
    padding: '30px',
    background: '#fff',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: '15px'
  },
  button: {
    width: '100%'
  }
}

class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        show: false
    }

    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this)
  }

  toggleModal() {
      this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
  }  

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props

    return (
      <div className={`${classes.modal} ${this.state.show ? classes.show : classes.hide}`}>
        <form className={classes.form}>
          <label htmlFor="aatitle-field">Title</label>
          <input className={classes.input} type="text" id="aatitle-field" name="title" value="" />
          <button className={`btn ${classes.button}`}>Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default injectSheet(styles)(Modal)
```

```